# When overriding enhance method of JwtAccessTokenConverter, Cannot convert access token to JSON on refresh token

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Problem occurs when I use super.enhance(token,auth) in return statement while overriding enhance() method of JwtAccessTokenConverter. It works fine when I return token only. But, additionalInfo shows only on the response body of the /oauth/token service and not in the JWT payload.

And, when I return super.enhance(token,auth), additionalInfo gets added into JWT payload (I checked at jwt.io). But, now token is not parseable.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
 TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
 enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter(), xyAuthTokenEnhancer2));
 endpoints
   .tokenStore(tokenStore())
   .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
   .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
   .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

I am trying to enhance access token as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class CustomJwtConverter extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
   @Override
   public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
     Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
     XYUser user = (XYUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
     additionalInfo.put("userId", user.getUserId());
     additionalInfo.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
     additionalInfo.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
     additionalInfo.put("companyId", user.getCompanyId());
     ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
     return super.enhance(accessToken, authentication);
   }
}
```

So, please help. why token is not parseable after enhancement and how to fix it? 
and, I followed this tutorial: [Spring cloud security with OAuth2](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake in configure method. 
You missed enhancerChain in endpoints object
My example is working fine with the following config method.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
                      .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, your code is working because you didn't add instance of CustomJwtConverter in the enhancerChain which means it will neither add additionalInfo into the JWT token nor response body of oauth/token service. I need to add additional info too. and, i am editing the question too. i think, in the beginning, it is not clear that what exactly i am trying to ask.